# "large" used as a noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

In "I'll have a large please," "a large" means "a large cup of something."
Is it correct to say "I'll have two larges please"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s perfectly acceptable in contexts where the first phrase would also make sense.

“Large” is essentially serving as an alias/name for a product served at a particular size in these situations.

Comment: Is it common in non-restaurant settings?

Comment: Yes, I believe it would be acceptable anywhere there is a variety of standard sizes. You’d probably want to make sure you use their terminology to avoid confusion, although with something like “large” or “small”, they’re fairly common and a lot of places will have a standard way of translating those, e.g., in Starbucks (UK) “small” would be interpreted as “Tall”. If you have a particular context in mind, let me know and I’ll give my thoughts.

Comment: @ChrisMack Do you mean that Starbucks call their less-than-huge measure of coffee a "Tall" coffee? No wonder I avoid Starbucks.

Comment: They certainly do. I guess they have a taller appearance than the wider larger sizes. Also, sometimes certain coffee shops (e.g., Caffè Nero) will serve small coffees in a tall, slim, glass cup, while larger ones are served in your commonly seen short, wide coffee cup, so maybe that’s where it comes from.